# A connect by query on all children

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by, hierarchical-query

Is there any way to have the `connect prior... start with` statement in Oracle to start with the first "child" in the table and then run the query for all the remaining children as well? I know how to use the statement for 1 child and get its ancestry, but I need the code to run for lots of different children in the table.

Let's suppose I have this code which returns a Component and Component's Color from table of components and the Component's parent and that is classified as a "Sample" and its color where component's parent ID is the ID of the parent for the component.

This is my schema:

```
Components table:
Component        Component_ID      Component_Parent_ID      Component_Label

Component_Color Table:
Component      Component_Color
```

Note: this is example code, not the one I am actually using, so if you silly errors, I am very sorry.

```
SELECT Component,
  FROM Components
 INNER JOIN Component_Color ON (Components.Component =  Component_Color.Component)
 WHERE Component_Label = 'Sample'
connect by prior  Component_Header.Component_Parent_ID = Component_Header.Component_ID
  start with Component.Component_ID = '2000';
```

Table Component has a lot of different components and I want the query to return not only the component with ID 2000 and its "sample" parent, but do this for all the children in the table "Components".

I can see how this can be done with a loop, but I cannot find what type of loop I can use for Oracle. Sorry, just starting.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  Version 11.2g supports recursive CTEs which can also be use for this.

Comment: Your "2000" is in double quotes which implies this is a column name. Is this correct or did you mean to use single quotes? The WHERE clause in a CONNECT BY is [evaluated _after_ the CONNECT BY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#sthref2221); did you know this and is it what you want?

Comment: @Ben: as the column is an "ID" it's probably not even a character column but should be used as a numeric value without any quotes.

Comment: It sounds as though you want to end up with a unique set of hierarchies, i.e. always start at the root. You _have_ to calculate what the root is first in order to do this... or your table might be set up in a manner which enables you to do this... lowest ID for instance?

Comment: Gordon - Version: Version 3.2.20.09 and I do not think I can use CTEs, but if you know any other method, please let me know. 

Ben - Yes, sorry - I just wrote it up as an example and did not double check it. Thank you. I will fix.

Comment: Too true @a_horse_with_no_name. user2707197, you're not using Oracle version 3 :-). `select * from v$version`.

Comment: There is no Oracle version 3.2.20.09. Wild guess: what happens when you leave out the `start with` completely? As all rows in the component table are "root" nodes and the child hierarchy is in component_header this might work

Comment: Hi, that worked. Thank you. Wow, cannot believe I did not try that. Post the answer and i'll select it. Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses in hierachical queries, because they run *after* the hierarchical processing. Here I think you should use `START WITH component_label = 'Sample'`.

```
 SELECT level, components.component_id, components.component_label, component_color.component_color
   FROM compenents JOIN component_color ON components.component = component_color.component
  START WITH components.component_label = 'Sample'
CONNECT BY PRIOR components.component_id = components.component_parent_id
```